# Passport Renewal before expiry

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, passport-renewals

I am an Indian citizen and my passport will expire in 2021. I am planning on moving to US for my Masters in 2019, for my VISA application will I face any problems as my passport will expire before i complete my MS which is a two year program. Most of my other colleagues have received a 5 year VISA, will i be able to receive the same.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to renew your passport early, nor do you need to apply to transfer your visa to a new passport. You can travel using a valid visa in an expired passport as long as you carry both old and new passports.

[Source](https://www.immihelp.com/visas/usa-visa-faq.html)

<sup>An afterthought: this applies specifically to US visas. Visas for other countries may need different treatment.</sup>

Comment: Thanks Just one more thing will I still get a student visa for 5 years for US

Comment: I don't know for sure but I'd guess not since _"Foreign students in the United States with F visas must depart the United States within 60 days after the program end date listed on Form I-20"_ ([Source](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/study/student-visa.html)). You're on a two year program, which implies leaving shortly after the two years is up.